# Problem generating PCD from rgbdslam

Tags: slam, navigation, pcl, bag-to-pcd, pcl-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've currently been using a bag file approach to run rgbdslam. The procedure I use is as follows:

I record a bag file with rgbdslam using the command:

> rosbag record /rgbdslam/batch_clouds /tf

And then I use the command:

> rosrun pcl_ros bag_to_pcd <bag_file_name> /rgbdslam/batch_clouds <destination_directory>

However, the error I get when running the above command is as follows:

> [ERROR] [######]: Frame id /base_link does not exist! When trying
> to transform between /batch_transform and /base_link.

I assume this problem likely has to do with applying the correct transform from the /tf recorded in the bag file. Is there an simple solution to this, or will I need to make an edit to the bag_to_pcd code to work for this specific case?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9723/problem-generating-pcd-from-rgbdslam/) by [Shark](https://answers.ros.org/users/264/shark/) on ROS Answers with karma: 241 on 2011-04-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> will I need to make an edit to the
> bag_to_pcd code to work for this
> specific case?

Yes, open bag_to_pcd.cpp and replace the one occurence of /base_link by /openni_camera

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2011-04-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1